# PHP datetime conversion giving me wrong time

Tags: php

I am converting 08/22/2015 10:56 PM CST to UTC

**Conversions**

- 10:56PM CST = 3:56 AM UTC
- Therefore the date should be: 2015-08-23 03:56:00 +04
- The code below is giving me: 2015-08-23 04:56:00 +04 (which is incorrect)

**Code in Repl**
https://repl.it/repls/LovelyKhakiExtension

```
    $datetime = '08/22/2015 10:56 PM';
    $tz_from = 'CST';
    $tz_to = 'UTC';
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s +h';

    $dt = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($tz_from));
    $dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz_to));
    echo $dt->format($format) . "\n";
```

Comment: in august CDT is in effect, not CST. Could this be the "issue"?

Comment: When I tried using CDT in the repl it gives me the same result.

Comment: might then be a wrong server-configuration?

Comment: No, some people said it has something to do with daylight savings time.

Comment: yeah, thats the difference between CST and CDT..

Comment: where do you have the info from, that it should be 3:56?

Comment: When I convert 10:56AM CST to UTC it gives me 3:56PM

Comment: Use `date('I', time())` to check if DST is there.